# Is this a small world situation/event?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I wanted to know if the following is a small world situation or merely a coincidence or both.

One of my friends has moved from London to Manchester to work for a corporate bank his name is Wasim. The person he has replaced in this particular role was also called Wasim. I mean it's not the most common of names.

After finding this out could you use the phrase 'It's a small world'?

Comment: What do dictionary (perhaps idiom dictionary) definitions say the adage means? // To be fair, while 'encountering the same situation unexpectedly in another place' is one definition given, I'd say the example you give isn't quite a fit. But it's certainly a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28it%27s%20a%29%20small%20world

> used to show surprise when one meets someone one knows at an
>   unexpected place or finds out that one shares a friend, acquaintance,
>   etc., with another person, "You know him, too? Wow, it's a small
>   world."

Your usage would not fit the context of "it's a small world" in this case Because you did not know the person. It would be more of a "What a coincidence!" response.

Comment: Hello, Steve. On ELU, queries are expected to be accompanied by reasonable basic research linked and attributed. This is why I didn't post an 'answer' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't understand the purpose of your comment, sorry. You meant that we want to urge the OP to do some basic research first and then guide them further?

Comment: Yes. Have you looked over the recommendations at the Help Center?

Comment: No. Will do so now.